# Exchange Message Tracking FAIL

Tags: exchange-2010

We're running Exchange 2010 on Server 2008 R2. All updates are installed.

We have a domain that cannot send us mail. They do not receive a bounce back email.

Running `get-messagetrackinglog -sender "sender@problemdomain.com"` reveals a list of messages with the EventID of "FAIL"

If I look at a specific message with running `get-messagetrackinglog -sender "sender@problemdomain.com" -messagesubject "Test" | fl`, I see that the RecipientStatus says

> {250 2.6.0  Queued mail for
>   deliver}

Note that this happens whether a real message is sent, or if I telnet locally on the Exchange computer using 127.0.0.1:25 and send a test message from that domain.

I have added the domain, and specific user to the BypassSenders/ByPassSenderDomains, but no avail.

We are running MS Security Essentials for AV, and once had SpamFighter Exchange module installed, but no longer.

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: What is the SourceContext for the FAIL Event?

Comment: Also, a couple/few people on the Interwebz have seen this due to Sender ID problems.

Comment: @Mary, this looks like a Sender ID problem. The user domain just got moved to office 365 and we are now able to receive their emails. Thanks for your input.